# Url hacking in lightning after comma text values are not capturing

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking, urlfor, url-encode

On Custom button i am passing the url and In below code snippet Notes__c field is long text area field. when i click on custom button values are populating but in notes field if user mention comma then from comma text is not populating.

For example if notes have text - the user, parent account values are active.
In above line only the User text is showing on button click.

```
   {!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Request__c/new? 
      &recordTypeId=0220W000001PEqPQz0&defaultFieldValues=Request_Name__c)='+ 
    (RetailCustomer__c.Request_Name__c)+Notes__c='+URLENCODE(RetailCustomer__c.Notes__c)}
```

Answer (score 2):

@cloudZigZag, you should use something like URLENCODE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT, ',', '%2c'))

Comment: please add an explanation as to why your solution works vs simply code dumping an answer  stating "this should work" or 'try this".

Answer (score 1):

1. The documentation for the base URL is inconsistent; in [this case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_constructing.htm&type=5) it recommends using $Action.Request__c.New or similar rather than hard-coding the host-relative URL form, but in [this case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5) it suggests a hard-coded host-relative URL.
2. Since you have taken the second approach, I don't believe you require the use of URLFOR.
3. You haven't used the correct syntax for the URL query parameters.
4. This isn't considered URL hacking any more since this is directly supported functionality rather than a workaround.

Try something like:

```
/lightning/o/Request__c/new?recordTypeId=0220W000001PEqPQz0
    &defaultFieldValues=Request_Name__c={!URLENCODE(RetailCustomer__c.Request_Name__c)},      
        Notes__c={!URLENCODE(RetailCustomer__c.Notes__c)}
```

You can see an example of this sort of usage in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5).

Comment: yes, but the problem is in that we have lookup fields also, if lookup field don't have a the value this thing will show the error

Comment: @cloudZigZag can you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/321472/edit) your question to explain your additional concerns in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

add nooverride=true in the url then try:

/lightning/o/Request__c/new?nooverride=true&recordTypeId=0220W000001PEqPQz0
&defaultFieldValues=Request_Name__c={!URLENCODE(RetailCustomer__c.Request_Name__c)},
Notes__c={!URLENCODE(RetailCustomer__c.Notes__c)}